# QGIS - Virtual Raster - Max number of grouped rasters

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, batch, virtual-raster

I'm facing an issue when I try to use the Virtual Raster process.
I'm asking to group 231 Raster, all located in different areas, not always concomitant.

The process is well executed, but the result shows nothing.

For now I tried these settings:

- Resolution: Highest (because I'm planning to perform remote sensing on these areas)
- Resampling algorithm: "Nearest neighbour" (nothing) ; "AVerage" (crash), Bilinear (nothing), Cubic convolution (nothing).

Sometimes QGIS crashes, sometimes the result show nothing.

Do you know if the problem come from the number of rasters I'm trying to group? It is working with 50 raster.

I'm trying to clip 231 raster, using a mask from a shapefile.
It is working with 1, but it would be extremely long to to it one by one.

[image: Crash Qgis]

I have this error when I try to save the result on my computer.

[image: Error]

Comment: Error messages and code should be posted as text, not as a screenshot. It is very difficult to read for some users and impossible for screen readers, and google. Please take the [tour] to see how this site works.

Comment: What does the log messages panel say? View - Panels - Log Messages

Comment: The issue with the layer not displayed properly disappeared after I closed and reopened the project. The other issue was coming from a mistake (was exporting an image into .vrt instead of .tif, because QGIS kept this extension in memory from a previous analysis and I didn't pay attention). I'll make sure, in the future, to post log into text and no screenshot.